"Shackled to BibTeX and who cannot (yet) move to BibLaTeX". What is that supposed to mean?
I am reading the documentation for "Better BibTeX for Zotero".
In there there is written:

Zotero does all its work in UTF-8 Unicode, which is absolutely the right thing to do. Unfortunately, for those shackled to BibTeX and who cannot (yet) move to BibLaTeX, unicode is a major PITA.

I also read  this post about the differences among bibtex/biber and natbib/biblatex.
So bibtex is an "external program that process bibliography information and act (roughly) as the interface between your .bib file and your LaTeX document" while biblatex is a "LaTeX package that format citations and bibliographies".
So what does the author mean with "shackled to BibTeX and who cannot (yet) move to BibLaTeX"?
He is comparing an external program with a latex package, isn't he?
Should "BibTeX" changed to "natbib", or should "biblatex" changed to "biber"?

well, the usual reason people can't use biblatex is that institutions require bibtex with a  .bst style (or they want thebibliography, of course - there's always that). and the block usually is on biblatex. it is not that somebody could use biblatex with the bibtex backend, but that biblatex styles are unacceptable regardless of backend. but this is not the same as being tied to natbib, which would be far, far more specific. so the author could explain the ins/outs better, maybe, but the claim seems reasonable modulo hyperbole.

Technically you are right that BibTeX and BibLaTeX play different roles in the processing and they can therefore not be compared directly. However, in everyday usage, the traditional way (BibTeX with natbib for example, or with apacite instead of natbib, or with another cite package, or without any package at all) is called BibTeX, and the alternative way (biber as backend with BibLaTeX as citation package) is called BibLaTeX. Therefore it makes sense to say that people use either BibTeX or BibLaTeX for their document.

You are absolutely right that BibTeX and Biber are external programs whose job it is (essentially) to read the relevant entries from the .bib file, sort and possibly modify them a little and then output them in a format digestible by LaTeX code for use in your document.
On the other side of story are natbib, cite, apacite, jurabib, biblatex (any many other packages) that provide a LaTeX-side interface for citations, bibliography lists etc. (But note that some basic support for citations is built into the LaTeX kernel and the standard classes.) You generally load these packages in your document and then use their commands to cite stuff.
So BibTeX and biblatex do not fall into the same category at first glance.

The \cite definition in the LaTeX kernel and all packages in that list except biblatex basically work in the same way: \cite is a glorified \ref command and the bibliography is typeset from the thebibliography environment, which is essentially an enumerate with built-in \label for each \item that then just typesets each item as-is. BibTeX is the tool that fills the thebibliography environment for you behind the scenes (via the .bbl file according to rules in the .bst files), so that you only see \bibliographystyle (which specifies the .bst file/"bibliography style") and \bibliography (which specifies the .bib file[s]) in your document. Some packages like jurabib use a very complex data structure in the thebibliography environment/the .bbl file, whereas other packages basically accept free-form input there. So there are some packages that work together with a wide range of .bst files, whereas some can only work with a small set. And vice versa.
In some sense biblatex has a very different approach. On a very abstract level, Biber (or BibTeX, since biblatex can technically be used with BibTeX, but you will give up a lot of its standout features if you do so) still processes the data from the .bib file and makes it available to the LaTeX side of things, which provides implementation of \cite and a bibliography printing command. But biblatex then gets the data in essentially machine-readable format from the .bbl, stores it and has it available at all times in the document.
Unfortunately, I know of no simple way to refer to these two approaches completely accurately. The biblatex approach can just be called "biblatex", but the first approach to citation/bibliography generation has no catchy name. Using any of the packages (e.g. natbib) to refer to it would be misleading in so far that no package is needed for basic functionality, because it is already built into the kernel. Calling it "LaTeX" is too generic. I usually use "BibTeX approach" or some such, which is not really accurate either, because BibTeX need not get involved at all: You can just write thebibliography manually. But it's the best I could come up with and to be fair: BibTeX is involved in most cases when the "BibTeX approach" is used; not that many people type thebibliography manually (and even fewer should do it).
Funnily enough, the "BibTeX approach" can actually be used without BibTeX or with BibTeX and the biblatex approach can be used with BibTeX or with Biber (in both cases the latter of the two options is usually preferred).
For most intents and purposes, whenever people cannot use biblatex that is due to the general nature or the biblatex approach (the approach is less attractive to publishers for several reasons) and not explicitly tied to which backend is being used.

Since the comment is about Unicode the most relevant distinction is BibTeX vs Biber, because BibTeX cannot deal with Unicode at all and Biber is fully Unicode-aware, whereas the LaTeX side of things is mostly on the same level of Unicode support no matter which bibliography/citation package you use (the TeX engine is slightly more important).
But then again, people are more used to hearing the name biblatex instead of Biber, because they load biblatex in their documents. (On Overleaf you can get a biblatex bibliography using Biber without ever having to explicitly invoke Biber or even knowing it exists. latexmk takes care of it all - you only see biblatex in your code.) So it is completely understandable that biblatex would be mentioned here and (as mentioned above) it is usually the case that when people are forced to use BibTeX they are forced not to use biblatex because of its general approach to bibliographies and not because it uses Biber.

PS: It is only slightly related to the question, but often people worry about whether or not their .bib files are compatible with both biblatex and BibTeX. While it is true that there are some fields in the standard biblatex data model that are not found in any of the BibTeX styles on CTAN and that some fields have different semantics in the biblatex standard data model than any of the BibTeX styles on CTAN, one should not forget that BibTeX technically only enforces the key-value bit of the syntax of .bib fields. The semantics of fields is completely up to the bibliography style. There is in fact considerable variation in the meaning of lesser used fields and entry types across the BibTeX style spectrum. BibTeX styles could in theory change the semantics/meanings of fields completely. It's just by convention that the fields and entry types introduced by the core BibTeX styles are shared more or less universally among styles. Extensions of this set are far less uniform. So don't lose track of the fact that even when you use different BibTeX styles you need to see if meanings are compatible. When you switch to biblatex its just much more likely that you could benefit from using a different field or that a field you already use has slightly different meaning now.
